# httpd doesn't run files

Tags: apache, webserver, fedora

I'm trying to install a web server on fedora 17, but it's not running any file I put on /var/www/html.

I checked the httpd.conf and it's pointing to this folder as document root. Also, if I access `http://127.0.0.1` from my browser it gives me the default Apache welcome page.

Comment: The files you put in `/var/www/html`... Were they PHP by any chance and you don't have it installed? Also, check to make sure the `html` folder has enough permission to be accessed by `httpd`.

Comment: I tried with PHP files and HTML files as well. No success at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that simply putting some files inside the `/var/www/html/` directory should make Apache display them. Here are some possible pointers that you might have missed.

Specify your `DocumentRoot` correctly in your `httpd.conf`. This is usually located at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

And make sure Apache allows people to access it, with something like

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Next, ensure that the permissions for your directories are correct, and allow people to `read` them.

```
sudo chmod -vR 755 /var/www/html
```

A quick breakup of the above command:

- `sudo` at the beginning tells the shell to execute the following command as `root`, so that you have enough permission to modify the directory.
- `chmod` is used to change access permissions of your files and directories.
- `-v` tells `chmod` to be `verbose` and spit out information about what it is doing.
- `R` stands for `recursive`. This will `chmod` the files inside `html` and sub-directories, if any.

*Additional read: [Wikipedia entry on chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)*

In case you are accessing your local server using a [hostname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname), make sure that you have defined it in `/etc/hosts`. For example, if you want `lappy` as your hostname, then your `/etc/hosts` will look something like

```
127.0.0.1   lappy
```